# Pass prefix mode flag to Angular 2 params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 app and want to pass in a mode with a true / false boolean flag that can be read by the app component like this:

`http://www.outapp.com/<appbase>/<mode>/<routes>/<child-routes>/<etc>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', // <my-app></my-app>
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  standAloneMode: boolean = true;

  // private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private loader: LoaderService) {
    standAloneMode = Router.SOMETHINGFROMTHEPARAMS;

  }
```

How can I pass the flag without disturbing the configured routes?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a path param like the following in your `route.ts` :

```
const routes; Routes = [
    ...
    {path: '/:mode/routes/child-routes/etc', component: YourComponent}
    ....
]
```

Then in your component, read the mode param like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(param=> {
          if (param['mode'] !== undefined) {
            this.mode= param['mode'];
            etc.
          }
    });
    etc.
}
```

Comment: Not a bad start but how can I dynamically pass in the mode without defining all the routes with the mode in them?

Comment: Using the base tag : `<script>document.write('<base href="' + service.getCurrentMode() + '" />');</script>` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) ???